# RPMDB Corruption Issue - RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, rpm, corruption, rpmbuild

**RPMDB got corrupted recursively on one of my server recursively.**

```
2016-07-07 14:14:31,296 - ERROR - error: rpmdb: BDB0113 Thread/process     6723/140691298633536 failed: BDB1507 Thread died in Berkeley DB library
error: db5 error(-30973) from dbenv->failchk: BDB0087 DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 -  (-30973)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

**I can able to fix it temporarily by rebuilding the RPMDB. Do we have any permanent solution for this?
How can we get to know the source of this issue on server?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check RAM using https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm for at least 24 hours. Check `dmesg`  for any IO related messages.